# How can I install a module in perl 5.16 WebService::AntiCaptcha

Tags: imagemagick

We tried to resolve the `imagetotext` captcha via perl. In this case we use anticaptcha services to convert a image to text conversion.

But the given module "`WebService::AntiCaptcha`" is not support in perl 5.16 windows OS.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Unable install "WebService::AntiCaptcha" this module in windows machine perl v5.16

Comment: Well, than that's it: if the creator of that module does not support Windows, you can't do anything about it